# Cannot modify a WriteBatch that has been committed

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, triggers, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to batch commit but when both the query returns something i am getting the error Cannot modify a WriteBatch that has been committed. how should i solve this issue? can anyone suggest any solution to do this is it to initialize two arrays and push the batch.commit() and then resolve the promise

```
module.exports = async (change) => {
  try {
    const timerSnapshot = change.before.data().timestamp;
    console.log(timerSnapshot, "before");
    const timerTimestampMinusOne = momentTz(timerSnapshot)
      .tz("Asia/Kolkata")
      .subtract(1, "days")
      .valueOf();
    const timerMinusThreeHours = momentTz(timerSnapshot)
      .tz("Asia/Kolkata")
      .subtract(3, "hours")
      .valueOf();
    const [profileSnapshot, threeHourReminder] = await Promise.all([
      db
        .collection("Profiles")
        .where("lastQueryFrom", ">", timerTimestampMinusOne)
        .get(),
      db
        .collection("Profiles")
        .where("lastQueryFrom", ">", timerMinusThreeHours)
        .get(),
    ]);
    const batch = db.batch();
    const batchArray = [];
    console.log(profileSnapshot.docs.length, "profile");
    console.log(threeHourReminder.docs.length, "three");
    profileSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      batch.set(
        db.collection("Timers").doc(getISO8601Date()),
        {
          timestamp: momentTz().tz("Asia/Kolkata").valueOf(),
        },
        { merge: true }
      );
      batchArray.push(batch.commit());
    });

    threeHourReminder.forEach((doc) => {
      batch.set(
        db.collection("Timers").doc(getISO8601Date()),
        {
          timestamp: momentTz().tz("Asia/Kolkata").valueOf(),
        },
        { merge: true }
      );
      batchArray.push(batch.commit());
    });

    await Promise.all(batchArray);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: You can find more information about [Batched writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#node.js)